# How to assign a variable to a SELECT query in flask/python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm trying to select a certain row (num) in a table using a SELECT query in mySQL. What am I doing wrong in the query line?

Tried many different syntaxes but most either return False or an EOL error.

```
@app.route("/users/<num>", methods = ['GET'])
def users_id(num):
    mysql = connectToMySQL('users')
    query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 'num';"
    users = mysql.query_db(query)
    print(users)
    return render_template('users_show.html', id = num, users = users)
```

The print statement returns () but I want the whole row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the `query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 'num';"` line. It seems like the query is literally `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 'num';"`, which is not what you want. Can you print `query` to see if the `num` input is substituted? I'd guess not. My guess is the existing query is turning up 0 rows because no row has an id of `num`.

I'd change that line to `query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {};".format(num)` so that `num` is inserted into the string.

Comment: Thank you so much. Spent hours trying to figure that out.

Comment: Glad it worked!